# React: animationOut not showing using Animated.css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animate.css

I have an example of a toggle that hide/display content.

I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-animated-css and it worked perfectly when displaying the content, meaning that after showing the content the animation is playing.

Now that I press the toggle button, the content instantly vanishes without animation.

I checked in the console and the class for the animationOut is working, but it seems that the content closes before the animation have the time to play, so it's hidden.

How to fix this issue ?

The working code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sorgz5?file=src/App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ContentComponent from "./content.js";
import { Animated } from "react-animated-css";

export default class toggleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isShowBody: false
    };
  }

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ isShowBody: !this.state.isShowBody });
  };

  checkbox = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className="switch switch-sm">
          <label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="select"
              onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
            />
            <span />
          </label>
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.checkbox()}

        <Animated
          animationIn="bounceInLeft"
          animationOut="fadeOut"
          isVisible={this.state.isShowBody}
        >
          <div>{this.state.isShowBody && <ContentComponent />}</div>
        </Animated>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I needed to remove `this.state.isShowBody` in `<div>`so the condition of the visibility is controller by `isVisible`.

```
<Animated
          animationIn="bounceInLeft"
          animationOut="fadeOut"
          isVisible={this.state.isShowBody}
        >
          <div>{<ContentComponent />}</div>
        </Animated>
```